# Cannot process result from temporary table variable within PL/SQL FUNCTION

Tags: sql, plsql, sql-function

I am trying to create a FUNCTION that should select some rows from the database, assign them to a variable called results of type temporary table, delete the actual records and then return the results which has been deleted. So first I am creating a temporary table like this:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE RESULTS (
    MESSAGE_ID NUMBER(19, 0),
    USER_ID NUMBER(19, 0))
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

and I plan to use it as a return type for my FUNCTION.
After that I am creating the actual FUNCTION like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DeleteMessages(
    deletion_date DATE
) 
RETURN RESULTS%ROWTYPE
AS 
deleted_messages RESULTS%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO deleted_messages from ( 
        WITH messages_for_deletion as (
            SELECT MESSAGE_ID, USER_ID FROM MESSAGE m
            join USER u on USER_ID = USER_ID
            WHERE u.STATUS = 'INACTIVE'
            OR u.END_DATE <= deletion_date
            OR m.PERMANENT_DELETE_DATE <= deletion_date)
        SELECT MESSAGE_ID, USER_ID FROM messages_for_deletion);
    DELETE FROM MESSAGE
    WHERE MESSAGE_ID IN (select MESSAGE_ID from deleted_messages);
    RETURN deleted_messages;
END;
```

First I create an CTE in which I join two tables and select filtered results based on some deletion rules. After that I want to assign those results to the variable deleted_messages which I return at the end. Before the returning clause I want to do the actual delete and therefore I am trying to select from the variable which obviously is causing the problem. I tried also :

```
WHERE MESSAGE_ID IN (select MESSAGE_ID from messages_for_deletion);
```

or even this weird approach:

```
(SELECT MESSAGE_ID from TABLE(cast(deleted_messages.MESSAGE_ID as array)));
```

but without any success. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? How will the returned values be used? As it stands, it looks like you could have potentially more than one row returned, but you're trying to store them into a single-row variable instead of a collection. That obviously won't work.

Perhaps you could use your GTT to insert the rows into before you delete them, and then your calling procedure could query that table?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The collection instead of single-row variable obviously makes much sense! I will try to change that. In regards to your question, those results will be used for some reports and stuff. I have an app that runs this FUNCTION as a scheduled job gets the results and creates the report. I am not very experienced with PL/SQL as you might expect :) If I change the variable to collection am I allowed to that selection afterwards? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you've already got a GTT (global temparary table) that you could use, I'd personally go with that (bearing in mind that you've set it up to delete the rows in there when a commit is done). You can convert a collection into something you can select from by using the `table()` function in SQL, inside PL/SQL (e.g. `select * from table(some_collection_name)`) but your collection must be defined as a SQL data type - e.g. `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE some_type_name IS ...`, so that it's available at the SQL engine layer. If it's a PL/SQL only type, you won't be able to do so.